# Is it possible to find and delete anything between two specified characters in an excel csv cell?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a csv file, where images links are added in one cell for one product. I want to remove text form ? to ,

I write this code:

```
=MID(A2,1,FIND("?",A2)-1)&MID(A2,FIND(",",A2),LEN(A2))
```

But its applied only on the first image link.

This is what I have:

```
/images/image1.jpg?1200x800=new, /images/image2.jpg?1200x800=new,/images/image3.jpg?1200x800=new, /images/image5.jpg?1200x800=new
```

Result I need:

```
/images/image1.jpg,/images/image2.jpg,/images/image3.jpg,/images/image5.jpg
```

Comment: Maybe do this in notepad++ before importing this to Excel?

Comment: I would try with REGEX. something like this should work: `=REGEX(A2,"\?.*new","","g")`. That will delete everything between ? and new.

Comment: Do you actually mean `delete` or do you mean `exclude from the formula result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in A1:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,","), y, LEFT(x,FIND("?",x)-1),y))
```

[image]

If you have Excel 2016 or earlier, which lack both the `TEXTJOIN` function as well as dynamic arrays, I suggest using a VBA routine to produce your desired output.

I used a regex match method to extract each segment, then joined them together. You could use a regex replace method, but since your original data has zero or one spaces after each comma, that would be the case in your result string also, so not as much under your control.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select **Insert/Module** and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=Images(cell_ref)` in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function Images(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim AL As Object
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "([^\?, ]*)\?"
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    If .test(S) Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For Each M In MC
            AL.Add M.submatches(0)
        Next M
    End If
End With

Images = Join(AL.toarray, ", ")
        
End Function
```

Comment: It's showing error #NAME?

Comment: @nasir excel version & platform?

Comment: Excel 2016 and Windows 10

Comment: @nasir I'd suggest a VBA routine. See my **edit**